# howto watch embedded html5 video with `blob:` url with external player

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, html5

Recently I stumbled upon `blob:http*` urls in `<video src=*>` on some websites. Is it possible to watch these in an external player? I tried VLC out of the box, but it doesn't seem to work, vlc cannot open it.

Comment: Show an example link that you want to play on external player!

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob Here's an example: http://tv2.hu/neoplayer/tv2/embed/222763_dino-vonat---ii.-evad-3.-epizod.html